# ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index in the case of sns.kdeplot

Tags: seaborn

> Bonjour, I do not understand what occurs.
>
> code is:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
for col in iris.iloc[:,2:4]:
    sns.kdeplot(iris[col], shade=True)
```

> that is OK, but:

```
sns.kdeplot(iris.iloc[:,2:4]);
```

> fails

```
----> 1 sns.kdeplot(iris.iloc[:,2:4]);
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
-> 1738     p = _DistributionPlotter(
   1739         data=data,
   1740         variables=_DistributionPlotter.get_semantics(locals()),
--> 111         super().__init__(data=data, variables=variables)
--> 605         self.assign_variables(data, variables)
--> 668             plot_data, variables = self._assign_variables_longform(
    669                 data, **variables,
--> 927         plot_data = pd.DataFrame(plot_data)
--> 614             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
--> 464     return arrays_to_mgr(
--> 119             index = _extract_index(arrays)
--> 625             raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

> Despite:

```
print(iris.iloc[:,2:4].index)
print(iris.iloc[:,2:4].columns)
```

> Regards, Atapalou

Comment: Add `data=`: `sns.kdeplot(data=iris.iloc[:,2:4]);`

Comment: Thank you sns.kdeplot(data=iris.iloc[:,2:4]); works.

Answer (score 1):

You question is unclear, but if I assume correctly you're looking to plot multiple curves in one command?

Your attempt failed as you're passing a 2D-array to `x`.

You either need to pass the 2D array to `data`, which has the naice side effect of enabling to set x-axis and legend titles (use `var_name` and `value_name` in `melt` to customize):

```
sns.kdeplot(data=iris.iloc[:,2:4], shade=True)
```

Or you can `melt` the input and use `hue`:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=iris.iloc[:,2:4].melt(), x='value', hue='variable', shade=True)
```

output #1:

[image: data parameter]

output #2:

[image: melt]